# Rendering with Backbone

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am trying to learn backbone and I was following along the code school backbone.js course to build my own backbone app. So far I have this code but I am having problems with rendering anything.

```
var PostsApp =  new (Backbone.View.extend({
    Collections: {},
    Models: {},
    Views: {},

    start: function(bootstrap){
    var posts = new PostsApp.Collections.Posts(bootstrap.posts);
    var postsView = new PostsApp.Views.Posts({collection: posts});
    this.$el.append(postsView.render().el);

 }
 }))({el : document.body});

PostsApp.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});

PostsApp.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

PostsApp.Views.Post = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<%= name %>"),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }

});

PostsApp.Views.Posts = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },

    addOne: function(post){
        var postView = new PostsApp.Views.Post({model:post});
        this.$el.append(postView.render().el);
    }
});


 var bootstrap = {
    posts: [
        {name:"gorkem"},
        {name: "janish"}

    ]
 }


 $(function(){
    PostsApp.start(bootstrap);
 });
```

I am just trying to create a very simple backbone app, CodeSchool is great but it not good at combining the pieces together and when I try to do that myself I am having problems.

So far the error I am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined" in the addOne function of the Posts View. Any help would be much appreciated.

edit: The answer below solved my initial problem, but I also set up an express server to send data to the front end with the code :

```
app.get('/tweet', function(req,res){
    res.send([{ name: 'random_name' }, {name: 'diren_gezi'}] );

});
```

and then I am trying to fetch this data to my collection like this :

```
var PostsApp =  new (Backbone.View.extend({
  Collections: {},
  Models: {},
  Views: {},

  start: function(bootstrap){
    var posts = new PostsApp.Collections.Posts(bootstrap.posts);
    posts.url = '/tweet';
    posts.fetch();
    var postsView = new PostsApp.Views.Posts({collection: posts});
    postsView.render();
    this.$el.append(postsView.el);

  }
}))({el : document.body});
```

But in the page the initial data (name: gorkem and name: janish) is displayed instead of the recently fetched data..

Comment: You're going to need to listen to when the collection gets the refreshed data as the view only knows about the initial set of data and not the fetched data by the time it renders. So do something simple like postsViews.listenTo(posts, 'sync', _.bind(postsViews.render, postsViews)); assuming you want to listen to the sync event (which I'm guessing is the one you want IE listen to any server communication). Create your view before you fetch.

Comment: thanks that works, whats the difference between fetch and sync? why didnt we listen 'fetch' but sync? and in general where is the best place to put the posts.fetch()? in the start function as it is ? or somewhere else?

Comment: There's no difference, if you read the Backbone source (or docs), there's no thing as a 'fetch' event ever fired. The way it's done is just 'sync' is fired for successful requests for the server. There's other events you can listen to, during a backbone network request, I would advise you to read at least their documentation on built-in events in the framework or source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem line (I see it in a few spots).

```
this.$el.append(postsView.render().el);
```

Try changing it to

```
postsView.render();
this.$el.append(postsView.el);
```

Render function doesn't return a function to self (the object with a reference to el).

Comment: thanks that was it! I am having another problem now.. about to edit my question, if you can have a look at it..

Comment: What happens when the render() method of a view has a `return this.` line. Can one use `this.$el.append(postsView.render().el;` now